# How to check website's log under IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7, web

Okay so I am fairly new with IIS. We have a server running here at my work and there are bunch of different websites running under IIS. One of the users reported that a website is down, and few minutes later the user sent another email saying it's running now. Now I want to look into the website's log files to see what went wrong and why did the website was down for few minutes. Can anyone advise how can I do this ? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find the application ID of the site with the problem in IIS. To do this click on your site name in IIS and click on advanced settings in the actions pane. Here you will see the ID of the site. Remember this.

Next you need to browse to C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles if C is the root of your file system and you have installed a default IIS instance. If you haven't then it should be within inetpub.

You will see a series of folders, one for each site setup in IIS, with a naming convention like this W3SVCx. X is what you application ID is.

Within this folder you will see active log files, one for each day the site was browsed too, with the date of the log within the file name (u_exYEARMONTHDATE)

It should be noted that IIS logs just have a log of **ACTIVE** connections. Not sure if this will help your question.